# Can you Host Windows Apps Online?

Tags: windows, open-source

Can you host demos of open source apps online, similar to how http://php.opensourcecms.com/ does for CMSs? For example, could you host a demo of Open Office for people to try out online? Maybe by connecting to a server that has Windows 7 installed or some Windows 7 simulator. How would you do that if you could?

Comment: Easy, unless you want it to work through the browser. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would certainly be possible, using something like a combination of remote desktop and virtual servers, however I haven't seen any solution like that.

The main reason for that is of course that it would require a lot of hardware. While a web server can handle thousands of concurrent users, a server running virtual remote sessions would be able to handle something in the range of 10-20 concurrent users.

Being somewhere around 100 times more expensive than running web servers, one can easily see why there is little demand for such technology.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways in which the visual display and mouse interaction of a Windows app can appear on a user's machine while actually running remotely.  Refer to—for instance—the [RFB protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFB_protocol) which is used by [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing).

It even appears there are some efforts to embed such remote screens into browsers using Flash.  I haven't tried it:

http://flashlight-vnc.sourceforge.net/

As @Guffa points out, this really won't scale very well.  But at smaller scales it's important to be aware of: I'm a big advocate of using approaches like this when someone has a niche legacy intranet application written in something like Visual Basic that only a few people use.  (Why rewrite something that already works in Ruby-on-Rails or whatever if only 10 people in the world will ever use it?)

At a meta-level, I think dropping users into an app they don't know how to use isn't always the best way of selling it.  With pervasive Internet video I think there's a big potential for screencasts to explain and introduce software, or teach them features:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screencast

It shows people what's possible, is easy for them to pass around, and is a lot less of a development/administrative/security effort on your part.